# Can we have icons for tags the way Stack Overflow has?

Tags: support, tags

Stack Overflow has images/icons on a lot of tags like for [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) and [CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info).

Can we incorporate this on Super User as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These [icons or images are reserved for companies that have contacted Stack Exchange Inc. and paid for the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable/) [privilege to advertise on such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean).

Comment: I never realized that tags could be monetized, TIL a cool business tactic :)